# Mass update OpportunityLineItem UnitCost (SalesPrice)

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

I have this issue every year....

We use opps to keep track of our renewable business year on year. The renewal opp is created automatically when the previous opp is closed/won. A product is created at that time on the renewal opp, at the same value as the previous opp, with a close date 365 days later.

Each year we ask the account managers to forecast the renewal value uplift achievable, I then have to update each ren opp with the new value.

Dataloader wont allow me to update OpportunityLineItem fields en-mass ( I'm assuming as it is running a lookup on Product2 which can only handle one query/update at a time?). I've tried excel connectors (old and new) which allow me to update one at a time (no quicker than dropping into the opplineitem in SF).

Any solutions out there?

Antony

Comment: Never heard about such DataLoader limitation. You don't see "Opportunity Product" on the list of objects? What if you'll tick "show all objects"? Or if you're running into some performance issues you could limit the batch size (so not update 200 records at a time but say 50 and see if the upload works)... Of course it'd be better to fix the root cause in the code ;) Without knowing more I'd say that report of reneval OLIs + import it back (with changes), either via DataLoader or Excel Con is OK-ish. You could also code some JS button to update all selected items on a listview for example.

Comment: It's a limitation on the OppLineProduct object, it just wont allow mass updates to the unit cost. Dataloader (and Excel connectors) error with "Can not add multiple products to opportunities" despite me not adding any, just trying to update a field!

Comment: I think it's your custom error, check the triggers & classes for this error message (Ctrl+H if you use Eclipse IDE). This code works in my dev edition like a charm: `List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Pricebook2.IsStandard = true LIMIT 5]){
 olis.add(new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = o.Id, PricebookEntryId = '01u7000000EBP6e'));
}
insert olis;` (select a pricebook entry that corresponds to standard price)

Comment: Or you could set the batch size in the Data Loader to 1 ;)

Comment: eyescream you are a genius. Set the batch to 1 worked. You have saved me days of work.

Comment: Cool :) I'm bit busy at the moment, can't convert the comments to a proper answer... If you'd like to post your own answer & later accept it I'll happily upvote ;) We're trying to improve our statistic of answered questions so the site can leave the "beta" stage.

Comment: You can absolutely mass update OpportunityLineItems. +1 eyes cream

Comment: Yeah - something else is going on I think. Just running an update on OpportunityLineItems should be totally possible in bulk dataloader updates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because abandoned

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Smart Tables for (related lists) and/or Smart-Mass-Update (for tabs).

Smart Tables: http://www.zaapit.com/page/smart-tables 
Smart-Mass-Update: http://www.zaapit.com/page/smart-mass-update